# No persistence provider exception

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, maven, jpa

I'm using netbeans, and I choosed eclipseLink JPA2.1.

```
    String persistenceUnitName="mypersistence";
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName);
    FacturesJpaController fjc = new FacturesJpaController(emf);
```

my persistence xml file is in META-INF:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
      <persistence-unit name="mypersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>database.mapping.Approvisionement</class>
        <class>database.mapping.Categories</class>
        <class>database.mapping.Factures</class>
        <class>database.mapping.Fournisseur</class>
        <class>database.mapping.Marques</class>
        <class>database.mapping.ProduitCategorie</class>
        <class>database.mapping.ProduitMarque</class>
        <class>database.mapping.Produits</class>
        <class>database.mapping.Profiles</class>
        <class>database.mapping.Users</class>
        <class>database.mapping.Usersstate</class>
        <class>database.mapping.Vente</class>
        <properties>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/piecedetachee?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
        </properties>
      </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

my pom file :

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>swing-layout</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev55-1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.luuuis</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcalendar-tz</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3-4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java/com/talcorp/piecedetachee/dalipiecesdetaches/icons</directory>
                <targetPath>${maven.compiler.target}/../com/talcorp/piecedetachee/dalipiecesdetaches/icons</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
```

everytime I run my application I got an exception :  No Persistence provider for EntityManager named "mypersistence".  what should I do to fix this issue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of working on this issue I decided to create a new maven project and I moved all my classes ( refactoring ) without changing the code, I built then it works fine, don't know what happened in the previous project folder but I suppose is a maven issue : perhaps .

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

In your POM.xml

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, is my build tag harmfull ? because it works fine in another project! I use this build tag to copy icons in the classloader search path because maven doesn't copy my ressource! is there any other idea ?

Comment: Try manually adding the jar file..The above jar (maven/adding manully) is not present in your project which is doing the damage